# clear ActiveMQ queue with stomp

Tags: activemq-classic, stompjs, stomp.py

Is there any way I can clear/delete ActiveMQ's queues from either `stomp.py` or `stomp-js` in Angular TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ does not provide a broker management API for STOMP clients, they are generally meant to be simple producers and consumers of data.  You manage ActiveMQ brokers using the Jolokia REST APIs that can be exposed.